# No Output for C Code in CodeBlocks IDE on Windows 10

Tags: c, codeblocks, windows-10

I'm using CodeBlocks for C, and having an issue. I'm doing something simple like printing `"Hello World"`, but I'm getting nothing in my CodeBlocks output box. its just blank and black :(.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know why? I have uninstalled and reinstalled CodeBlocks, and it still doesn't work. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code; It compiles, runs, and outputs the expected text and newline without any problems using gcc. Perhaps you need to take a closer look at how you're running this code in Code::Blocks. Perhaps you wrote this in a file your project isn't expecting to find main() in?

Comment: Im not sure where it would trying to find the main. brand new computer, downloaded codeblocks fresh. i downloaded the binary - codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe

Comment: Just cleaned up a few things and added relevant tags!

Answer (score 0):

Post the `XML` project file (with extension `.cbp`) for the concerned `Code::Blocks` project that you have compiled which starts like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<CodeBlocks_project_file>
    <FileVersion major="1" minor="6" />
    <Project>
    ....
```